# JS Cross Domain запрос на другой сайт

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

Я делаю скрипт для Tampermonkey и мне нужно сделать запрос на другой адрес. Само собой мне выдает ошибку Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Как я могу сделать запрос, учитывая что сайтом, с которого он делается, я не владею, и дописать в php разрешение на Cross Domain запросы я не могу?

Comment: Если ничего противозаконного - самое простое решение, связаться с владельцем\админом домена, объяснить ситуацию и просто тупо попросить. Я не глумлюсь. Я абсолютно серьезен. Естественно, вас обоих ждет долгий поиск компромисса.

Comment: @Qwerty_Wasd других способов нет? Я делаю неофициальное расширение, и никакого резона помогать мне у владельцев сайта нет. Может можно перенаправить запрос через свой собственный сервер?

Comment: если можно было бы сделать это без соответствующих заголовков с обратной стороны, вместо CORS придумали бы что-то еще.
CORS кстати блокирует не все. Если у вас простые запросы GET\POST\HEAD и заголовки Accept и Content-type\-language, то проблем по идее быть не должно. В противном случае - адьос.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#terminology

Comment: В данном случае проксируй запросы через свой сервер

Comment: Да, можно перенаправить запросы через свой сервер. CORS только в браузере реализовано на данный момент.

Answer (score -1):

Установите в запросе режим

`mode: 'no-cors'`

На стороне PHP пропишите

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```